# Submitting form via ajax, one way or two ways?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, action

What's better of this two options:

```
1. $.post( '/ajax/action', function(data) { doResult(); }  );

*This option has to receptors: ajax.php and action.php*
```

or

```
2. $.post( '/action', { typerequest: 'ajax' }, function (data) { doResult(); }

*This option has only 1 receptor: action.php (if typerequest exists, returns ajax result)*
```

Form without ajax looks like:

```
<form action="/action">
```

Answer (score 0):

No difference between those two, really.  Pick whatever is easier for you.

I think it is easier to have Ajax scripts handled independently (that is option 1).  The other script is going to have to print out a whole page on its own.  That means you have to conditionally display it (e.g. by typerequest) and you end up wrapping a lot of stuff in conditionals.

But really either way is fine.  Pick whatever you are most comfortable with.  Just be consistent.